# Displaying a list of names and adding a comma & and to the last name on the list using php

Tags: php, mysql, character-trimming

I want to display a list of names and separate them with a comma and the last name should be separated with an "and" using php. Please I need help.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
                  $bdaypersoname="";
                  do {
                     $bdaypersoname .= $row_Recordset2['Name']." , ";

                      } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); 
                      $bdaypersoname= rtrim($bdaypersoname, " , ");
                      echo $bdaypersoname;
                    ?>
    </p>
```

Comment: As in: "Please stop using PHP's archaic, insecure, *and* deprecated mysql_ API" ?

Comment: can you post sql you used ?

Comment: Here is the sql code.................................... mysql_select_db($database_twconn, $twconn);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT Name, DOB FROM tb1 WHERE month(DOB)=month(curdate())";
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $twconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, with some demo names

```
$array = ['Alex','Bob','Collins','Danny'];
echo join(' and ', array_filter(array_merge(array(join(', ', array_slice($array, 0, -1))), array_slice($array, -1)), 'strlen'));
```